# Is vaping a healthier alternative to smoking?

Tags: public-health, smoking

I’ve heard from some people and advertisements that vaping is healthier than smoking, and vaping should be more popular because it causes less damage to the lungs. Is this really true, or have I been severely misinformed?

Comment: Please provide a link and define what you mean with vaping. There are a lot of substances that could possibly vaped. Do you care about specific ones?

Comment: The normal, mainstream vaping where a flavored liquid is heated to produce inhaleable steam, according to the Wikipedia page on vaping: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_cigarette

Comment: So you include non-nicotine vaping?

Comment: No, i’m asking the comparison of effects of nicotine vaping and nicotine smoking.